# Straight to classify the JSON data

Tags: php, json

There is a sorted list of questions without classification and I want to sort this list of questions. Because the system of the school works like this. I tried to do this, but I could only do this because I had little PHP knowledge.

In the JSON file, the first part is the question, followed by 4 options and the question begins again.

The amount of questions does not change. Always 4.

Currently JSON file:

```
$jsonData = '["questionText1","option1","option2","option3","option4","questionText2","option1","option2","option3","option4","questionText3","..."]'; // x150 text
```

My code:

```
$jsonParse = json_decode($jsonData, true);
foreach ($jsonParse as $json) {
    $cikis[] = array('q' => $json[0]);
}
var_dump($cikis);
```

Goal:

```
$jsonData = [
             {'q':'questionText','o1':'option1','o2':'option2','o3':'option3','o4':'option4'},
             {'q':'questionText','o1':'option1','o2':'option2','o3':'option3','o4':'option4'}
            ]
```

I looked for a question like this but couldn't find it. What do I have to do to classify the question and question options separately? like the example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [`array_chunk`](https://www.php.net/array_chunk) to split your source data into chunks of five items, since each grouping always consists of 1 question + 4 options.

```
$chunks = array_chunk($jsonParse, 5);
```

This will give you an array of five-item chunks, with each chunk containing the question as the first item `[0]`, and the options as items `[1]...[4]`. If you want to turn them into associated arrays, you can do that for example using [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/array_map) and [`array_combine`](https://www.php.net/array_combine):

```
$namedChunks = array_map(function($chunk) {
    return array_combine(['q', 'o1', 'o2', 'o3', 'o4'], $chunk);
}, $chunks);
```

This will give you an array with named keys, which you can `json_encode($namedChunks)` for the output you're looking for. (Your example isn't valid JSON, though!)

A foreach loop and a "manual" building of the associated arrays will also work, and probably will be marginally faster. I'm in the habit of using straight-up loops in code where performance adds up (either frequently called, or with massive data), and using the more elegant `array_*` functions in favor of more explicit and readable code, where raw performance is less consequential.

Comment: I've recently grown more tolerant of `array_map` et al. Used to hammer it all with `foreach` for fifteen odd years. Does make the coder reading it feel loopy at sufficient volume. God knows the "elegant" functions were crap performers especially in the era before PHP7. An `array_map` in the wrong place would cost you dearly. It still does, e.g. if you call a method some hundreds times from a loop and it uses `array_map` instead of `foreach` to transform data. Yet to run benchmarks on the fresh-out-of-the-oven PHP8, hopes are the gap between array_*s and raw loops is narrower still.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_chunk()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) to split an array into samesized chunks:

```
<?php

$numberOfElementsPerChunk = 5; // 1 question + 4 options

$jsonData = '["questionText1","option1","option2","option3","option4","questionText2","option1-2","option2-2","option3-2","option4-2","questionText3","option1-3","option2-3","option3-3","option4-3","questionText4","option1-4","option2-4","option3-4","option4-4"]';

$jsonParse = json_decode($jsonData, true);

$chunks = array_chunk($jsonParse, $numberOfElementsPerChunk);

$result = [];
foreach ($chunks as $question) {
    $set = [
        'q' => $question[0],
        'o1' => $question[1],
        'o2' => $question[2],
        'o3' => $question[3],
        'o4' => $question[4],        
        ];
    $result[] = $set;
}

print_r(json_encode($result));
```

Output:

```
[{"q":"questionText1","o1":"option1","o2":"option2","o3":"option3","o4":"option4"},{"q":"questionText2","o1":"option1-2","o2":"option2-2","o3":"option3-2","o4":"option4-2"},{"q":"questionText3","o1":"option1-3","o2":"option2-3","o3":"option3-3","o4":"option4-3"},{"q":"questionText4","o1":"option1-4","o2":"option2-4","o3":"option3-4","o4":"option4-4"}]
```